# Elixir Hound wait for page to load

Tags: elixir, selenium-chromedriver, hound

I'm submitting a login form and trying to capture the HTML afterwards using elixir / hound. After submitting I run `page_source` and get nothing. If I wait for a second (for the page to finish loading) then I get back the html.

Is there a way to make hound wait till the page is finished loading?

I'm currently doing: `:timer.sleep(2000)` as a work around, hoping for a better way :/

Comment: What code are you using to navigate / post your form?

Comment: I'm navigating to my login page, adding username / password, and then i run `click({:class, "loginButton"})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I do:

Create a function that repeatedly checks for a test condition every 100ms, in this case I'm waiting for particular text to appear by using 
[visible_page_text](https://hexdocs.pm/hound/Hound.Helpers.Page.html#visible_page_text/0)

```
@tag timeout: 6000
test "My Test" do
  assert wait_for(fn -> Regex.match?(~r/Success/, visible_page_text()) end)
end

def wait_for(func) do
  :timer.sleep(100)
  case func.() do
    true -> true
    false -> wait_for(func)
  end
end
```