# How to assert an element is present after a click in Hound?

Tags: selenium, elixir, hound

I'm using Hound as webdriver framework for leveraging Selenium in Elixir. I'm testing facebook account creation. After I fill out a negative test (firstname = Roberto, lastname = asdlkfj;)I click submit and I am trying to get an error for not having a correct last name. The problem is Hound isn't waiting for the element to be displayed and returns an element not found error. How can I handle this and have the test wait until the element is loaded? Here's my code:

````
  test "Last name with random characters" do
    counter = :rand.uniform(100)
    navigate_to "https://www.facebook.com"
    first_name = find_element(:name, "firstname")
    fill_field(first_name, "Jorge")
    last_name = find_element(:name, "lastname")
    fill_field(last_name, "asdfja;lsdf")
    email_input = "robbie#{counter}@gmail.com"
    email = find_element(:name, "reg_email__")
    fill_field(email, email_input)
    confirm_email = find_element(:name, "reg_email_confirmation__")
    fill_field(confirm_email, email_input)
    password_input = "123456Test"
    password = find_element(:name, "reg_passwd__")
    fill_field(password, password_input)
    #Birthday
    birth_month = find_element(:css, "#month > option:nth-child(5)")
    birth_day = find_element(:css, "#day > option:nth-child(25)")
    birth_year = find_element(:css, "#year > option:nth-child(22)")
    click(birth_month)
    click(birth_day)
    click(birth_year)
    #gender
    select_gender = find_element(:css, "#u_0_s > span:nth-child(2)")
    click(select_gender)
    sign_up_button = find_element(:name, "websubmit")
    click(sign_up_button)

    search = find_element(:id, "#reg_error_inner")
    # found = element_displayed?("#reg_error_inner")
    IO.puts(search)
    # assert found == true
    # :timer.sleep(10000)
   end```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106480/elixir-hound-wait-for-page-to-load does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `search_element` instead of `find_element`. `search_element` will return `{:ok, element}` on success and `{:error, error}` on failure. If you just want to assert the element exists, then you can:

```elixir
assert {:ok, _} = search_element(:id, "#reg_error_inner")
```

If you want to also have it in a variable for further processing, then:

```elixir
assert {:ok, element} = search_element(:id, "#reg_error_inner")
```

If you want to convert it to a boolean, then:

```elixir
match?({:ok, _}, search_element(:id, "#reg_error_inner"))
```

Comment: I tried this but got an error.                                                                                           
    `1) test Password too short (ElixirSdetExerciseTest)
     test/elixir_sdet_exercise_test.exs:144
     match (=) failed
     code:  assert {:ok, _} = search_element(:id, "#reg_error")
     right: {:error, :no_such_element}
     stacktrace:
       test/elixir_sdet_exercise_test.exs:172: (test)` Same kind of testing criteria applies

Comment: That means the element is not present, which I thought you wanted to assert? If you just want a boolean, then see the updated answer.